# Git excluding files while Pull Request

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

We have have a repository wherein  we have branches specific to environment, Dev, UAT, PROD..
Each environment has a file which contains specific set of configurations.. We cannot make this file as a property file or as a template file..

When we raise a Pull Request for the code to merge from dev --> UAT or dev --> PROD. The file will get overrided..

.gitignore will just hide it while merging but it get merged once we approve and merge the code ..

Answer (score 2):

You should do a merge without commit like follow:

```
git checkout prod-branch
git merge --no-commit uat-branch
git restore properties-file
git commit
```

Comment: ., We are more looking for a solution that works with pull request. Because we are working with Jenkins .. So the client will just merge the PR and the build gets triggered automatically.. The solution you helped me will require minimum knowledge on git .. which is not acceptable by clients.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the recommendation from the Git developers is not to do this.  It is possible to use a custom merge driver for this file, but that will not work with pull requests because the hosting platform won't have your custom merge driver.  Since the configuration for the merge driver tool isn't stored in the repo, they won't even know the name of your tool, nor would they execute an arbitrary program even if they did (for security reasons).

If you still want to use the custom merge driver, you can create a bot to merge your pull requests for you.  For the custom merge driver, configuration for this file would be stored with the `merge` attribute in `.gitattributes`, and you'd set the name of the merge driver in the config.  Set the `gitattributes` manual page for details.

Otherwise, the recommended approach for this is to either use a template file and fill it in from the environment, or to store all the configuration in a directory and then copy or symlink the right one for your environment when deploying.  Note that you of course shouldn't store any sort of secrets in the repository at all, so reading data from the environment is the only secure approach there.